# Take doesn't listen for actions to be dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, redux-saga

I have tried to use `yield take(action.type)` in my saga.

```
function* foo() {
  console.log('pausing')
  yield take(action.type)
  console.log('passing')
}
```

I made sure I dispatched the right action in my useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(action())
}, [action])
```

I also made sure the action is dispatched after the saga is set up correctly.

The actions are defined in Redux Toolkit's slice

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'app',
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    appMounted: (state) => {
      // ... some state updates if needed
    },
    buttonClicked: (state) => {
      // ... some state updates if needed
    }
  }
});

export const { appMounted, buttonClicked } = appSlice.actions;
export default appSlice.reducer;`
```

Also the action type I am using in the take effect is the exact same action type I am dispatching.

The issue is that, `'pausing'` got printed, but after I dispatch `action`, `passing` is not getting printed.

Comment: There is not enough code to say for sure, but my suspicion is that `action.type` is undefined. Can you show how your `action` is defined?

Comment: @MartinKadlec thanks. I defined the actions in my redux toolkit's slice

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the `redux-saga` middleware to [middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/redux-integration#middleware) when creating the redux store.

A working example:

`store.ts`：

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import appReducer from "./app.slice";
import saga from "./saga";

let sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        app: appReducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({ thunk: false }).concat(sagaMiddleware),
});

sagaMiddleware.run(saga);

export default store;
```

`saga.ts`:

```
import { take } from "redux-saga/effects";

export default function* foo() {
    console.log("pausing");
    yield take('app/appMounted');
    console.log("passing");
}
```

`app.slice.ts`:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const appSlice = createSlice({
    name: "app",
    initialState: {},
    reducers: {
        appMounted: (state) => {
            // ... some state updates if needed
        },
        buttonClicked: (state) => {
            // ... some state updates if needed
        },
    },
});

export const { appMounted, buttonClicked } = appSlice.actions;
export default appSlice.reducer;
```

`App.tsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import { appMounted } from "./app.slice";

export default function App() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(appMounted());
    }, [dispatch]);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
            <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")!;
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
);
```

Logs of the console:

```bash
pausing 
passing
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76985996-fq8xfx?file=/src/index.tsx)